# warning: s comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

while i am running the above title is appearing as error

```
#include <stdio.h>
 int main()
 {
  int i;
  char name[20];
  printf("Enter name: ");
  scanf("%s",name);
  printf("Your name is %s",name);
  while(name[i]!="\0") 
  {
    i++;
    if(name[i]==" ")
    {
        strcpy(b[i],name[i]);
        printf("copied name: ");
        scanf("%s",b[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

while i am running this it is showing this error why? warning: comparison between pointer and integer.

Comment: please edit the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

"\0" is a string, '\0' is a character. As you comparing a character, you need the latter.

Also, as pointed out by  chqrlie, there are many other issues - you need to check your compiler warnings/errors and fix them all. For example,

- `name[i]==" "` is wrong with the same reason.
- where is `b` declared?
- where is `i` initialized??

Comment: That's only the beginning: the same holds for `name[i]==" "`, `b` is undefined, `strcpy` is given characters instead of strings, `scanf` probably wrong too...

Comment: yes, many issues you pointed out, he needs to compile and fix them himself. I updated some anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are many errors/ warnings in your code.

1. It should be '\0'. Not "\0";
2. You have not declared b[];
3. Initialize i=0;
4. Instead of strcpy, you can use another method which is shown in below code.
5. Also, you should not use scanf in last line. You should use printf. scanf is used to take input from user. printf is used to print the results.

Code-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,n;
    char name[20],b[20];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("Your name is %s\n",name);
    while(name[i]!='\0') 
    {
        b[i]=name[i];  // to copy from name[] to b[]. Instead of strcpy
         i++;
    }
    printf("copied name: ");
    for(n=0;n<=i;n++)
  {
      printf("%c",b[n]);  // to show the copied result.
  }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```